# No logro enviar los datos de tres formularios iguales con un solo submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario que se repite tres veces para enviar tres informaciones del mismo tipo una sola vez.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <form id="form1" method="post">
 <tr>
   <input type="date" id="fechaActual" value="">
   <input type="number" name="salidas">
   <input type="number" name="paradas">
 </tr>
 </form>

 <form id="form2" method="post">
 <tr>
   <input type="date" id="fechaActual" value="" >
   <input type="number" name="salidas">
   <input type="number" name="paradas">
 </tr>
 </form>

 <form id="form3" method="post">
 <tr>
   <input type="date" id="fechaActual" value="">
   <input type="number" name="salidas">
   <input type="number" name="paradas">
 </tr>
 </form>
<input type="button" id="all" value="Submit all Forms">
```

JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#all").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    document.getElementById("form2").submit();
    document.getElementById("form3").submit();
});
```

Si alguien me puede dar una luz con esto, el botón submit simplemente no se envía.
he probado de otras maneras pero solo me envió el primero o el último, no los 3.

Los forms deben ser tres y tienen más campos, he disminuido la cantidad para un mejor entendimiento.
Deben ser tres o más para no tener que enviarlos de manera separada y que no se haga repetitiva la tarea que enviar 3 por separando cuando se puede enviarlos juntos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes:

- Agrupar los formularios en uno solo, y enviar los datos como arrays.
- O evitar el envío de los formularios por separado, agrupando sus datos y realizando un único envío.

La primera opción es bien fácil, la segunda requiere un poco más de preparación. Yo veo más natural la primera, y entiendo que realmente es lo que necesitas, y lo que buscabas cuando pintaste los tres formularios.

Sería así:

En el HTML, pones un único formulario, y los name de los inputs los retocas para que se envíen arrays:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="date" id="fechaActual1" name="fechaActual[1]" value="">
                <input type="number" name="salidas[1]">
                <input type="number" name="paradas[1]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="date" id="fechaActual2" name="fechaActual[2]" value="">
                <input type="number" name="salidas[2]">
                <input type="number" name="paradas[2]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="date" id="fechaActual3" name="fechaActual[3]" value="">
                <input type="number" name="salidas[3]">
                <input type="number" name="paradas[3]">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="both" value="Submit Both Forms">
    </div>
</form>
```

Notas:

- He arreglado tu table (por ejemplo, le faltaban las celdas td).
- He añadido name a los elementos fechaActual, y un número al id para distinguirlos.
- He cambiado tu botón a type "submit", pero puedes hacerlo como prefieras.
- A tu form le falta la propiedad action, es recomendable que se la pongas.

Cuando envíes el formulario, desde PHP recibirás esto como contendido de $_POST:

```
array(
    'fechaActual' => array(
        1 => '[valor de fechaActual1]',
        2 => '[valor de fechaActual2]',
        3 => '[valor de fechaActual3]',
    ),
    'salidas' => array(
        1 => '[valor de salidas1]',
        2 => '[valor de salidas2]',
        3 => '[valor de salidas3]',
    ),
    'paradas' => array(
        1 => '[valor de paradas1]',
        2 => '[valor de paradas2]',
        3 => '[valor de paradas3]',
    ),
);
```

De forma que es fácil recuperarlos y trabajar con ellos.

No obstante, si prefieres recibir los datos con una estructura más afable en el array, puedes pintar los inputs así (atento a los name):

```
                <input type="date" id="fechaActual1" name="datos[1][fechaActual]" value="">
                <input type="number" name="datos[1][salidas]">
                <input type="number" name="datos[1][paradas]">
```

He puesto sólo los correspondientes al conjunto 1, para el 2 y el 3 sólo tienes que poner el número correspondiente.

Y en $_POST['datos'] en PHP recibirás un array donde cada elemento será un (sub)array con los elementos 'fechaActual', 'salidas' y 'paradas'. Osea, muy fácil de tratar. Lo dejo para ti ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, José. Voy a probar a ver que tal.

Comment: muchas gracias por tomarte un tiempo para ayudarme con este tema. 
He probado atentamente con lo que me has enviado pero el botón submit no funciona. 

En https://jsfiddle.net/z19cvds6/
Y me sale el siguiente error que no encuentro como corregirlo:
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#149:37'>149:37</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'submit')"

Comment: Si el pones type="submit" al botón, quítale el id, y quita el javascript que le da la funcionalidad click, ya que con type submit no lo necesitas para enviar el formulario, y ahora mismo te está fastidiando después de retocar el HTML.

Comment: He intentado y sigue sin funcionar, José.

Comment: Te tiene que faltar o sobrar alguna tontería porque ahora lo que tienes no es más que un formulario HTML, deberías ser capaz de que te funcione. Si te atrancas, búscame en Google y contacta conmigo.

Comment: Gracias, te he contactado a través de tu página.